# A sequence that converges normally but not uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Consider the sequence of complex-valued functions $f_n(z)=z^n$, for $n=1,2,3,\dots$. How to show that
this sequence does not converge uniformly to $f(z)=0$ on all of the unit disc. However it converges
uniformly in every compact subset of the unit disc to $f(z)=0$?

Comment: $f_n(1-\frac1 n ) \to \frac1  e$. On a compact set $|z| \leq r$ for some $r<1$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks. But why does this sequence converge in every compact subset to $0$?

Answer (score 1):

To see that $f_n$ doesn't converge to $0$ uniformly on the entire disc, use the fact from *real* analysis that the corresponding real functions $f_n(x) = x^n$ don't converge uniformly to $0$ on $x\in(0,1)$. (This is a famous example from real analysis. And it's not too painful to prove: pick $\epsilon>0$ small enough so that the $x^n$ "poke out" of the $\epsilon$-tube surrounding $0$, for $x$ close to $1$.) This implies that uniform convergence doesn't hold in the complex case, because uniform convergence of the *real* functions is necessary (but not sufficient) to ensure uniform convergence of the complex functions.

On compact subsets of the unit disc, I'd try comparing $z^n$ with the partial sums of the geometric series: $$|z^n| < |1|+|z|+|z^2|+ \dots + |z^n|. $$ Since the geometric series converges *absolutely* and uniformly on compact subsets of the unit disc, the RHS converges absolutely as $n \to \infty$; so the left side converges as well. To see that it is uniform, use the [Weierstrauss M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test). (The terms $M_n$ can come from the above bound, using the formula for a finite geometric sum.)